# JQuery Change event if it is not a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [this Nestable script](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable) and I need the ability to add a link to the movable navigation items and make it clickable.

Currently when I add a link to the `<li>` item the whole navigation tries to move as it is part of the jQuery code. I need the ability to ignore the jQuery if the item is a physical link `<a>`.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but cancelling the propagation on the click

```
$("li a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

It might be mousedown instead of click

Comment: Worked Spot on with Mousedown and not click